# Default find-and-replace to have regex enabled

Tags: user-interface, replace, atom-editor

Why does Atom always unselect the regex option in the find-and-replace menu? I know I can use a shortcut to re-enable it but it only seems to stick for the current session. If I close and then reopen Atom, the find-and-replace menu once again defaults to having regex unselected. Who are these coders who don't search using regex?!? I assume there's an undocumented setting I can use in config.json but I didn't see anything in the GUI settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always start that way. What I do is to assign easy shortcuts that only apply in the search editor. This is in my .atom/keymap.cson (open by wenu, edit, keymap, or select "Application: Open your keymap" from the command palette:

```
'.platform-linux .find-and-replace':
  'ctrl-/': 'find-and-replace:toggle-regex-option'
  'ctrl-*': 'find-and-replace:toggle-selection-option'
  'ctrl--': 'find-and-replace:toggle-case-option'
  'ctrl-+': 'find-and-replace:toggle-whole-word-option'
```

Comment: Great, this is a super helpful work around, I'll add a shortcut to toggle regex.

Answer (score 1):

Well after I accepted @netizen's answer I did some research and looked at the atom/find-and-replace package itself and specifically it's settings file: https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/blob/master/lib/find-options.coffee

There's a setting `find-and-replace.useRegex` noted there which seemed to be a boolean, so I modified my Atom config.cson (Command Palette or Settings > Open Your Config > edit config.cson) like so:

```yaml
"*":
  "find-and-replace":
    useRegex: true
```

This had the desired effect—regex is turned on by default when I use find/replace now. Note that, since find-and-replace is an additional package, settings changes to it don't go under "core" in your config.cson.

There are other boolean settings for caseSensitive, wholeWord, and inCurrentSelection, too.

Comment: Take care of adding it. I added `"*"` as root, next to `core`, and all my previous settings in `"core"` disappeared. And, there's no backup for `~/.atom/config.cson` The right setup is having `"*"` as root and all `"find-and-replace"`, `core`, `editor` etc... as siblings on nested level. Btw, I know Atom is discontinued, but maybe some of us are still using it.